# Uploadify rename more than one file

Tags: php, uploadify

I'm using uploadify on a project, and I've got the php script renaming a single file, but I'm unsure how to repeat the process if more than one file is uploaded at a time?

My php script is below...

```
$targetFolder = '/img/uploads'; // Relative to the root

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {

  $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
  $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;

  $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
  $unique_hash = hash_hmac("md5", file_get_contents($_FILES['Filedata']['name']), SALT);
  $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $unique_hash .'-'.$_POST['userId'].'.'. $fileParts['extension'];


  #$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

  // Validate the file type
  $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
  $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

  if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
  } else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
  }
}
```

Comment: Foreach through what?

Answer (score 0):

When you use ajax, you can send a request for every file just one by one then you wont have to use a foreach or you send the form at once and use the code below here.

When you send all file together you will be using in your form something like this: `name=userfile[]` so you can foreach the files like this:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) 
{     
 $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($file['name']);
 if (!move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) 
 {
  echo set_e('error','Image ['.$i.'] not uploaded','');
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do more than one? Uploadify uses jQuery ajax to process the files? It might look simultaneous but it processes one file at a time via ajax. It will call your upload.php as many times as there are files in the queue. So if your function works for one file, it will for the rest. You just need to make sure it's writing a unique filename in the directory every time the function is called whic it looks like it does. Uploadify handles looping through each file name then calls your upload script.

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Look at the network console with Chrome or Firebug and upload a bunch of pictures with on the demo. you'll see the upload.php script is called for each file.

FYI,
I used to use uploadify but I changed to PLUPLOAD http://www.plupload.com/. Supports multiple uploads too but better documented and easier to use with great api's.